# Chart with pair of lines with single legend entry

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Specifically, with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) I'm trying to create bollinger bands on a LineChart.  I'd like both lines to be the same color and share a single legend entry but I can't seem to find a way to do this.  It seems if I have 2+ lines I need to have 2+ legend entries.

Also is there a way to stack the legends vertical when positioned below the graph?

Comment: Mostly reading the documentation to see what could be tried but there wasn't much.  Setting the label as null or blank did not seem to work as that was the first obvious guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mentioned is just the `Legend` that is auto generated depending on your data.

But the `Legend` also has a `setCustom(...)` method that allows you to set any amount of colors and labels that you like.

```
 Legend l = chart.getLegend();
 l.setCustom(integerColorArray, stringLabelArray);
```

More on that in the [**wiki**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend).

Comment: Great that should work.  My problem was I was looking for a way to customize an auto generated entry when they either need to be all auto generated or all custom.